# How does one embed a file inside of an image? iOS iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, file, metadata

There is an app on the app store called active photo (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/active-photo/id366798464?mt=8) that allows you to embed a hidden image or .exe file inside of an image. I would like to know how to do this regrading adding images to images, kinda like sub images in the original image.

I've been looking into metadata but no tag seems to be big enough to hold an NSData representation of the second picture.

How would one go about adding any type of file to an image, either through embedding or metadata, that would allow the image to be sent though email and or text message and still retain the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

I would imagine the simplest way of hiding a file inside a JPEG image is just to alter its pixel data in such a way that the compression doesn't damage it but is subtle enough that an interceptor can't detect the hidden data.

Comment: According to that article it seems as though when you modify the image code in that way that that data would be lost when sent over email, etc. The way I tried doing it, in one of my previous questions, was to turn the image into NSData, append the second image inside the NSData using a separator string, and then saving it. This worked on my device and I was able to read both pictures UNTIL I emailed them or texted them. The emailing and texting removed the data I added in and I was left with just the original image. Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: Appending the second image doesn't work because the addition isn't defined in the image format, and any conversion will either ignore it or choke on it.  For certain image formats you may be able to embed "informational" data (such as comments fields JPGs).  Otherwise you'd need to use some sort of steganography.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 the only idea that comes to my mind in this case is that they store not an image itself in the other image, but secret image's location or identifier on the device (and then hide the secret image on the device itself in some form). Then sending the image to other system really doesn't carry the secret image. This doesn't exclude steganography, of course.

Comment: Is it possible to create custom metadata tags, because then I could create one without a limit on characters and then fill it with the NSData of the second image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with JPEG because it's a lossy compression so you would end up corrupting the embedded file. But PNG uses a compression method similar to Deflate, which is loseless.

I have started writing a program like this. The idea was to hide bytes of data by splitting them into the least significant bits of pixels' color channels. Let me do some examples.

An RGB-8 image represents a pixel with 3 bytes, one for red, one for green and one for blue. I store 3 bits into red channel, two into green (human eye is more sensitive to green color) and 3 into blue. So I embed one byte per pixel. Similarly with RGBA-8 image I do 2-2-2-2. This of course involves some bitwise operations.

Things become more interesting with RGB(A)-16 images, where there are two bytes per channel. I use the entire least significant byte of every channel with minimal distortion (worst case 255 / 65535 = ~3.9%) and store up to 3 or 4 bytes of data per pixel. Not bad!! 
Moreover there are no complex bitwise operations in this case, a single assignement does the job.

There are lot of improvement to it. I thought to ask the user a password, hash it and seed a secure pseudo random number generator, then no longer move pixel by pixel but instead asking the generator for a new random index.

The drawback of this solution is that the more data has already been embedded, the slower it becomes, because the generator will give more and more occupied indices. But it is much more secure in this way. To make it even more safer I thought to introduce noise data in the untouched pixels, in order to hide the positions of the true data.

As you can see you can do a lot with PNG images! If you are interested I can give the code I wrote so far.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing this. Does this persist if one were to email/sms/imessage the picture?

Comment: If the image is not explicitly converted to other formats your data persists forever. So yes, it can be emailed or even published on a web page. Send me an email at the address you find in my profile, in the next days I will send you the C sources :)